# trouble with output directory for OpenCV VideoWriters

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm a math undergrad and have little programming experience. I'm interested in computer vision however. Tried to follow the Learning OpenCV book but its slightly outdated. How do i save the resulting video file in my linux home directory? for eg "/home/user/..", thanks in advance, this is my first post and i know i won't be disappointed. I'm compiling on eclipse btw, and i'm not too familiar with the arguments setting.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 int isColor = 1;
 int frameW  = 640;
 int frameH  = 480;
 int fps     = 25;

 CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
 assert( capture != NULL );

 cvNamedWindow( "Webcam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

 CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter(
   "out.avi",
   CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),
   fps,
   cvSize(frameW,frameH),
   isColor
  );

 IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

 while( (frame = cvQueryFrame( capture )) != NULL ) {
  cvWriteFrame(writer, frame);
  cvShowImage("Webcam", frame);
  char c = cvWaitKey( 33 );
  if ( c == 27 ) break;
 }

 cvReleaseVideoWriter( &writer );
 cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
 return(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried passing the full path to `cvCreateVideoWriter`?

```
 CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter(
   "/home/user/out.avi",
   CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),
   fps,
   cvSize(frameW,frameH),
   isColor
  );
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I've reinstalled OpenCV with ffmpeg installed properly. but now i get this error. any idea?
===================================================================
relocation error: /usr/local/lib/libhighgui.so.2.1: symbol sws_getContext, version LIBAVCODEC_52 not defined in file libavcodec.so.52 with link time reference

Comment: I'm not totally sure, that maybe sounds like an issue with how ffmpeg was compiled. Are you building it yourself or installing it as a package? I'm not very familiar with doing this, but from googling around [here](http://www.rainsoft.de/projects/ffmpeg_opencv.html) it looks like you may need to build ffmpeg with the `--enable-shared` option.